# minimizing the integral of a function over square sets.

Tags: real-analysis, global-optimization

Hi!

I'm interested in some problems, but to be honest i'm not sure of the field they belong to.

Let $h(x,y)$ be a bivariate function on $X^2$, where $X$ is some nice topological space (for instance $[0,1]$, or $[0,1]^2$.)

1. What is  $$\inf_A \int_{A\times A} h(x,y)dxdy?$$
   where $A$ belongs to the class of measurable sets (I think one can use other classes of sets, like the closed sets, or the open sets, etc...).
2. What is $$\inf_Y \sum_{x,y\in Y} h(x,y)?$$
   where $Y$ belongs to the class of finite sets.
   What is $$\inf_Y \sum_{x\neq y\in Y} h(x,y)?$$

I think the answers are difficult, but if one has any idea or an idea of a link with something else, it is already a lot.

Comment: Here is a possible connection: if you take the $Y$ in the discrete case to be subsets of some finite set then you have a clique problem in graph theory, where $h$ represents edge weights.

Comment: Yes it is interesting as well, could you tell me more or indicate a reference?